# Changing all elements of highligthed type in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I use the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) which highlights all the corresponding elements that are the same as the one being highlighted. As shown below ( **"col-sm-6" - purple highlight** )

[image]

*(I think it is Productivity Power Tools doing this. I installed it the same time i upgraded to 2013 , not sure if it is a default setting now)*

What I would really like to be able to do is to change all the elements that are highlighted at the same time. So if i want to change **"col-sm-6"** to **"col-sm-4"** I want to be able to just hold down a shortcut key which will change all items highlighted.
I have a very strong feeling that this functionality exists.

It seems a lot like the functionality used when you select multiply lines while holding "alt" and then typing.

I have searched around, but cannot seem to find a shortcut for this. I could just do a copy and replace but it would be a lot easier to just hold down "ctrl" while typing.

Comment: Yes, it does exist in visual studio.

Comment: Could you expand on that please? Really keen to know how.

Comment: see my answer below. let me know if this is not what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does already exist. If you change a variable name, all the other instances can be renamed at same time (see below). Moment you change the name, a small red bar will be seen below the name -> press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on that bar; it will ask you to change all other instances.

Also, for highlighting a text; there is already a extension ti visual studio present, see here http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb

[image]

Comment: That is actually the reason why i think this functionality exists. I do use what you have described here , but this only works in the c# editor and not the Html editor. Which is what i really what to effect. If i "(ctrl + ".")" in the html editor all i get is the option to remove child elements

Comment: @gerdi, that's really strange? have never tried though. In such case I believe my answer won't add much value to this question.